Activity Context VS Activity VS Activity Scoped Injection in Hilt
I have some questions regarding Hilt library based on this article I have read :
When (and When Not) to Pass the Activity Context in Android

Why we should inject Context instead of activity object in good pattern design?
Is annotating @ActivityContext in enough or should we also specify @ActivityScoped annotation?
If we just add @ActivityScoped like permission helper below and we forgot to add @ActivityContext, will Hilt or dagger scope their dependencies automatically or should I ensure to Hilt that this context is Activity Context and is tied to the activity injected this object?
Will dagger allow mixing scopes like Menu Class? Chat GPT answers that it allows mixing scopes but I doubt this. As I learned from  course by Vasiliy Zukanov that objects scope their dependencies.

https://www.udemy.com/course/dependency-injection-in-android-with-dagger/?couponCode=LETSLEARNNOWPP
Those are some UI related objects that has been injected into hilt, which design is a good practice and which is avoided in Hilt
///no scoping
//this might be scoped to the activity injected this object
//that means when this activity recreated new instance will be used //but we provide activity context
///this will be tied to lifecycle of the activity
    public class PermissionHelper {  

        private final Context mActivity;
    
        @Inject
        public PermissionHelper(@ActivityContext  Context activity) {
            this.mActivity = activity;
        }
}

///@ActivityScoped //this might be scoped to the activity injected this object that means when this activity recreated the same instance will be used ///but we forget to add @ActivityContext will hilt know it by itself
@ActivityScoped
public class PermissionHelper {  

    private final Context mActivity;

    @Inject
    public PermissionHelper(Context activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

}
//Menu is @ActivityScoped and shared references is @Singleton // will dagger allow mixing scopes
@ActivityScoped
public class Menuu extends BaseObservablee<Menuu.ListenerMenu> {

       @Inject
        public Menuu(Context context, SharedPref sharedPreferences) {
            applicationcontext = context;
            this.sharedPref = sharedPreferences;
        }}

Solved:
Depending on what I have experimented with, I will add more details:

First Question the answer is: we should avoid inject activity to not loose decoupling which is the main purpose of DI, provide layout inflator, Activity context,  and avoid using context in lower domain layer.
The answer is no not enough we should specify Activity context so hilt can differentiate between application and activity context.
the answer is no we should consider both activity scope and activity context (Scoping dependencies ensures that they are created and destroyed with the corresponding activity, which helps manage memory efficiently. Providing activity context instead of the application context ensures that dependencies are aware of the current activity's lifecycle)
If the scope is not specified, objects in Hilt will scope their dependencies like what has been taught by Vasiliy Zukanov, but if scope were defined like shared preferences, this singleton object will be shared during the lifecycle of the app.

Hope this information will be beneficial for all...Correct me if I am wrong
